# Read XAML tag as string in C#

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp-xaml

I have lots of buttons that all have the same click event but I would like to know which button was actually clicked without writing separate C# code for each one. If I could just read the XAML tag as a string in C# I could make it work but I can't figure out how to do it. Any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: Really not sure what your exactly meaning, but couldn't you use the `Name` Property of your XAML Tags? Provide some Code for better understanding of your Question.

Comment: You already get the button that was clicked in the event. You'll have to explain more clearly how that's not enough and what you'd get out of the XAML that you don't have now.

Comment: Name would work just as well but I can't get that to work either. Do you know how I can read the XAML control's name property and store it is a string in C#? I've tried things like: string buttonName = this.Name; but that doesn't return the Name.

Comment: Kuhmonen: I'm new to working with XAML and C# so I may just not know the obvious way to do this. Can you explain what you mean by "you already get the button that was clicked"? I just don't know how to read and store things like Tag and Name from the XAML control once I'm in C#.

Comment: In your `Button_Click` method, the `sender` argument is the button you clicked, but you'll need to cast it as a `Button` to access it's properties. e.g. `var button = (Button)sender;`, then you can access it's properties such as `button.Name`, `button.Content`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Tone!! That's exactly what I was looking for!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Home_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as RadioButton;
        if (button != null)
        {
            switch (button.Tag.ToString())
            {
                case "Home":
                    this.MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(Views.Home_Page));
                    break;
                case "Settings":
                    this.MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(Views.Settings_Page));
                    break;
            }
            Header.Text = button.Tag.ToString();
        }
    }
```

[To more options](https://mohamedsaqer.wordpress.com/category/xaml/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just cast the sender as Button, then cast the button.Tag as string ?

```
Button _sender = sender as Button;
string tag = _sender.Tag as string;
```

And then of course you can do a switch on the tag value to know which button was the sender.